# How can I write a regex search for SQL statements missing a table schema in VS Code?

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to use visual studio code to search our code base for SQL statements table declarations are missing the schema using a regex expression.

So far I've got this

```
(from|inner join|left join)((\s|\r|\r\n)*)(dbo|sys)
```

which selects where the schema is included, but I'm having trouble excluding where the schema (or table name) is not `dbo` or `sys`
e.g. "Select * from company" should be found, where "Select * from dbo.company" should not.

I though it would be

```
(from|inner join|left join)((\s|\r|\r\n)*)(!dbo|!sys)
```

but that selects nothing.

and I'm aware this misses `APPLY`s, `INSERT`s, etc.

Comment: Are you searching through application code for ad-hoc sql or within sql objects like procedures, view and functions? What about where optional `inner` clause is excluded, `outer` is included, `full` joins etc and multiple spaces or other allowable characters exist?

Comment: Related: [Regex lookahead, lookbehind and atomic groups](/q/2973436/11107541). Can you add an example of some texts that you would want selected and some that you wouldn't want selected?

Comment: why not just search for JOIN... Also, don't forget APPLY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do it using negative lookahead (see [Regex lookahead, lookbehind and atomic groups](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2973436/11107541)):

```
(from|inner join|left join)((\s|\r|\r\n)*)(?!(dbo|sys)\.)\w+
```

The "`\w`" above just matches word characters (`[a-zA-Z0-9_]`), but you can replace it with a more suitable regex. Add quotes or other characters as needed if you also want to match quoted names (use `?` for optional match- like `"?`)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this seem to work quite alright in my proc collection:

```
(\s|\r|\r\n)+(from|join|apply)(\s|\r|\r\n)+\w+(\s|\r|\r\n)+(\w+|\()
```

I'm basically skipping the lookahead since it never works, instead i try to match everything that doesn't contain two part name ie:
from somevalue (alias or index hint)

It won't match quoted names, but it's probably easy enough to change \w+ to a quoted version of it